# Kotlin flow - emitting value of combined 2 flows only when second flow emits a value

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I want to combine two flows in that way: the combined flow emits value only when both flows emitted a value and only in moment when second flow emitted its value. When it occurs, next value is emitted again when both flows emitted new values.
My pretty drawing for better understanding the expected result:
[image: First preview image]

But it may appear situation like that:

[image: Preview image 2]

Answer (score 1):

I think [`zip`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/zip.html) function is what you need:

```
flow1.zip(flow2) { result1, result2 ->
    // ... use results
}.launchIn(viewModelScope)
```

`zip` fires when each pair of value is emitted. Here is a good [article about `Flow` operators](https://betterprogramming.pub/learn-how-to-combine-kotlin-flows-317849a71d3e).

Comment: But as I see, order of flows doesn't matter? I want to emit value only when second flow emits value (and the first emitted before).

Comment: I guess the order doesn't matter. The resulting flow will emit only if there are new pairs.